# Ambiguous type in Haskell type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to use parametrized type class. Below is my source code:

```
class (CContext3D c k v) => CBuilder3D c a k v where
    build3D :: c -> a -> String -> HSL HLangJS HLangJS
```

At compilation I receive the following error:

```
Could not deduce (CBuilder3D c a k0 v0)
from the context: CBuilder3D c a k v
bound by the type signature for:
   build3D :: CBuilder3D c a k v =>
                              c -> a -> String -> HSL HLangJS HLangJS
```

The following code works correctly:

```
class (CContext3D c KeyContext3D String) => CBuilder3D c a where
    build3D :: c -> a -> String -> HSL HLangJS HLangJS
```

How is it possibly to release instance of class depending from k and v types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is a call to your `build3D`. From the context of that call, the compiler has to find a proper instance. This involves finding values for variables `c a k v`. However, the type of `build3D` do not mention `k v`, so it would be impossible to find those.

More concretely, if we had

```
instance CBuilder3D c a K1 V1 where ...
instance CBuilder3D c a K2 V2 where ...
```

their related `build3D` function would have exactly the same type, and the compiler has no way to choose one of those.

Possible solutions:

If possible, you should use functional dependencies or type families to state that the value of `k` and `v` are determined by the other parameters. This might be the case or not, depending on your specific class.

Otherwise, you could try enabling `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications`, and keep the ambiguous type around. However, at every call, you now will have to specify those types explicitly as in `build3D @t1 @t2 @t3 @t4 x1 x2 x3` where `t1,...` are the types for all the variables `c a k v`. Not terribly convenient.

Another option is to make `k,v` to appear in the type with a proxy:

```
import Data.Proxy

class (CContext3D c k v) => CBuilder3D c a k v where
    build3D :: proxy k -> proxy v -> c -> a -> String -> HSL HLangJS HLangJS
```

now each call should be something like `build3D (Proxy :: Proxy K1) (Proxy :: Proxy V1) x1 x2 x3`.